# rewrite _index.php to home.html

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking at some old code for a company website, basically familiarizing myself with different coding practices. One thing I noticed is that the main website page is _index2.php and redirects to a page called home.html

I'm curious about this. I've been reading about RewriteRule in .htaccess but the underscore in front of the index2.php file is throwing me off. the home.html file seems to be generated by the website's CMS and imports the php file into it. This is something I haven't really seen before.

To messs around a bit I'd like to create a _index3.php and have it imported into home2.html for testing/experiments/learning. I generated a home2.html page using the site CMS and now I'd like someone to guide me in how to import the _index3.php file using RewriteRule (If that's how it's done)

Sorry for the long winded question, I'm learning and I thought a thorough explanation is the way to go.

Comment: So you want every file named like `_index#.php` to redirect to `home#.html`?

Comment: Not yet. Baby steps so I'd just like to get one page working first and then go from there. I'm mostly just experimenting and messing around to see how things work.

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^_index\.php$ /home.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, just trying that now.

Can I ask what the [L,NC] part means? The rules in the htaccess files here all end with [L,E]

Comment: `L` is for Last and NC is for `no case` comparison. See all flags here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Not yet, but I wanted to try a few things first and do some more reading and see if I could figure it out.